# wp_insert_site() is triggering database error in a unit test

Tags: multisite

I have a WP "unit" test, run in multisite mode, that looks like this:

```php
class EffectsTest extends WP_UnitTestCase {
  public function test_wp_insert_site() {
    $id = wp_insert_site([
      'title'      => 'My Site Title',
      'domain'     => 'foo.multicare.org',
      'meta'       => [
        'whatever' => 'whatever',
      ],
    ]);

    $this->assertNotEmpty($id);
  }
}
```

The test passes but it's triggering the error:

```
WordPress database error Can't reopen table: 'a' for query DELETE a, b FROM wptests_2_options a, wptests_2_options b
                        WHERE a.option_name LIKE '\\_transient\\_%'
                        AND a.option_name NOT LIKE '\\_transient\\_timeout\\_%'
                        AND b.option_name = CONCAT( '_transient_timeout_', SUBSTRING( a.option_name, 12 ) )
                        AND b.option_value < 1605216174
made by PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main, PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run, PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->doRun,
PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run, PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run, PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run,
PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->run, PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run, PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runBare,
PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runTest, MultiCare\Integration\EffectsTest->test_wp_insert_site, 
wp_insert_site, do_action('wp_initialize_site'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
wp_initialize_site, populate_options, delete_expired_transients
```

The actual error originates in [`delete_expired_transients()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_expired_transients/#source), which appears to be deleting from two aliases to the same table, `$wpdb->options`:

```php
 "DELETE a, b FROM {$wpdb->options} a, {$wpdb->options} b..."
```

MySQL doesn't seem to like that. So my question is, **is there a way to prevent this without patching WP Core?** Seems like a core bug to me, but perhaps I'm missing something.

(The actual test calls a function from my application code, so I'm not just testing `wp_insert_site()`. But that's irrelevant here because it's the call to `wp_insert_site()` that's triggering the error.)

Comment: I don't know, but I do see you're PHP serialising 2 values into a single post meta, it would be more secure and flexible t just use 2 meta keys, e.g. `mc_central_data_id` and `mc_central_data_site`

Comment: @TomJNowell more secure how?

Comment: To be clear, that is trusted data. It's not actually user input. And we do want it to be open/dynamic for reasons that are not really relevant here; we won't be querying by those nested fields.

Comment: PHP serialized data leaves you open to deserialisation attacks, there are no advantages here to serializing, it is unnecessary, adds complexity, and adds an attack vector. Serialising provides no advantages that cannot be gotten by other means

Comment: By that token, the auto-serialization in `update_post_meta()` is never advantageous and is always less secure, so you should just never rely on array meta fields, is that right?

Comment: Yes, and if you must store structured data do it via JSON encoding, though that has its own attack vectors, namespacing keys is a much better solution that has none of those downsides, and has the upside of being queryable. Removing auto-serialisation in core would break a huge amount of legacy code, which is why it's kept. Going back to your unit test case, does this run if you run it on its own without any other code? `delete_expired_transients` looks okay to me, and it's run on WP update and install. Does running it directly via `wp shell` cause the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced the same issue, and the solution was calling WP_UnitTest_Factory_For_Blog::create instead. In OP's case it would become:

```php
class EffectsTest extends WP_UnitTestCase {
  public function test_wp_insert_site() {
    $factory = new \WP_UnitTest_Factory_For_Blog();
    $id      = $site_factory->create(
      [
        'title'      => 'My Site Title',
        'domain'     => 'foo.multicare.org',
        'meta'       => [
          'whatever' => 'whatever',
        ],
      ]
    );

    $this->assertNotEmpty($id);
  }
}
```